# Selenium Python. Click on radio-button does not any affect

Tags: python, selenium, radio-button, webdriver

First of all sorry for my english.

I have a page with radio-buttons.
Here is the html code of the button I want to click.

```
<label class="radio-button__radio radio-button__radio_side_right radio-button__radio_next-for-pressed_yes" for="uniq13988671">
    <input id="uniq13988671" class="radio-button__control" type="radio" value="1000">
    <span class="radio-button__text">все</span>
</label>
```

my python script with selennium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains as ac

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url_with_elements")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

my_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='1000']")
ac(driver).move_to_element(my_button).perform()
my_button.click()
```

This button should reload the page with all elements (at least 1000) but it doesn't work. 
Ther's no any errors and element respond on method .get_attribute('id')

```
>>> my_button.get_attribute('id')
u'uniq13988671'
```

here is full html code of row with radio-buttons:

```
<td class="b-layout-table__cell">
    <div class="b-banners-per-page i-bem b-banners-per-page_js_inited" onclick="return {"b-banners-per-page":{"urlObject":{"hash":"","query":{"cmd":"setPageSize","subcmd":"showCamp","cid":"8868621","ulogin":"*mylogin*"},"file":"main.NWluTm99mAw1N.pl","directory":"/registered/","path":"/registered/main.NWluTm99mAw1N.pl","relative":"/registered/main.NWluTm99mAw1N.pl","port":"","host":"direct.yandex.ru","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"direct.yandex.ru","protocol":"https","source":"https://direct.yandex.ru/registered/main.NWluTm99mAw1N.pl"},"optimalBannersOnPage":20}}">
        <span class="b-banners-per-page__title">Объявлений на странице: </span>
        <div class="b-banners-per-page__buttons">
            <span class="radio-button radio-button_size_s radio-button_theme_normal i-bem radio-button_js_inited" onclick="return {"radio-button":{}}">
                <label class="radio-button__radio radio-button__radio_side_left" for="uniq13988675">
                <label class="radio-button__radio radio-button__radio_checked_yes radio-button__radio_pressed_yes" for="uniq13988674">
                <label class="radio-button__radio radio-button__radio_next-for-pressed_yes" for="uniq13988673">
                <label class="radio-button__radio" for="uniq13988672">
                <label class="radio-button__radio radio-button__radio_side_right" for="uniq13988671">
                    <input id="uniq13988671" class="radio-button__control" type="radio" value="1000">
                    <span class="radio-button__text">все</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Here's the image of how it looks like "step by step"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB5Gi.png

I'm looking at other questions but they don't help me.
Thanks for any help.

**ADD**: If i use Selenium IDE addon for firefox. this button clicked fine.

If need more info - please ask.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, can you edit your post and add the error?  I'm guessing the code is not finding the element, and that can be caused by a couple of different issues.  If the element you are trying to click is in a `frame` or `iframe`, or if the element is slow to load.

Comment: Add more info. The element was found successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've handle my problem use construction like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains as ac

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url_with_elements")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

# my_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='1000']")
button_parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/div/div/span/label[5]")
ac(driver).move_to_element(button_parent).perform()
button_parent.click()
ac(driver).send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```